# Given initial moles of weak acid, find moles of conjugate base to be added to get a final pH (volume unknown)

Tags: acid-base, buffer

I am preparing notes on buffers and I came across this problem on a website:

> Given 10.0 mmol of a weak acid HA with $\textrm{p}K_a =5$, how many mmol of NaA needs to be added to have a final $\textrm{p}H = 5$?

The solution method shown used the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation

$$\textrm{p}H = \textrm{p}K_a + \log_{10} \frac{ [\ce{A-}] }{ [\ce{HA}] } \hspace{1in} (\textrm{Eqn 0})$$

Plugging we get

$$[\ce{A-}] = [\ce{HA}] \qquad \iff \qquad n(\ce{A-}) = n(\ce{HA})$$

Thus, at equilibrium the moles of $\ce{A-}$ needs to equal the moles of $\ce{HA}$. Next, the author *assumes* that this implies the initial moles will also equal

$$n(\ce{A-}) = n(\ce{HA}) \implies n_\circ (\ce{A-}) \approx n_\circ (\ce{HA})$$

Since $n_\circ (\ce{HA}) = 10$ mmol this means $n_\circ(\ce{A-}) = 10$ mmol which means the amount of NaA needed is also 10 mmol.

I wanted to solve the problem without making that assumption.

**Mass Balance** At equilibrium the "atoms" $\ce{A}$ appear only in the HA and $\ce{A-}$ and they only come from the initial $\ce{HA}$ of 10 mmol or from the added moles of $\ce{NaA}$ which equals the moles of $\ce{Na+}$

$$n(\ce{HA}) + n(\ce{A-}) = 10 + n(\ce{Na+}) \hspace{1in} (\textrm{Eqn 1})$$

**Charge Balance**
$$n(\ce{H+}) + n(\ce{Na+}) = n(\ce{A-}) + n(\ce{OH-})\hspace{1in} (\textrm{Eqn 2})$$

**Equilibrium** for the weak acid
$$ K_a = \frac{ [\ce{H+}] \cdot [\ce{A-}] }{ [\ce{HA}] } = [\ce{H+}] \,\frac{n(\ce{A-})}{n(\ce{HA})} \hspace{1in} (\textrm{Eqn 3})$$
**Equilibrium** for the water
$$
      K_w = [\ce{H+}] \cdot [\ce{OH-}] \hspace{1in} (\textrm{Eqn 4})$$
In the above we know $K_a = 10^{-5}$, $K_w= 10^{-14}$, and from the p$H$ we know $[\ce{H+}] = 10^{-5}$ mmol/mL.  The fourth equation gives $[\ce{OH-}] = 10^{-9}$ mmol/mL.

However, the final volume of the solution $V$ is not given. No volumes are given. So $n(\ce{OH-})$ can not be found from $[\ce{OH-}]$.  This means the first three equations can not be used to get $n(\ce{HA})$, $n(\ce{A-})$, and $n(\ce{Na+})$. Notice dividing the first equation by $V$ does not help since it 10 mmol would become $10/V$.

Is this correct?  Without knowing the volume I can not find a value for $n(\ce{Na+})$ unless I make the assumption given above?

**Clarification Notes Added**: Yes, Eqn 0 is just the negative logarithm of Eqn 3 (i.e., HH is no more than an algebraic rearrangement of the Law of Mass Action). Therefore, it is not surprising that Eqn 3 also gives $n(\ce{A-}) = n(\ce{HA})$ (after plugging in $\textrm{p}K_a=\textrm{p}H$).

The point is that I do not want to then assume that equivalence of the ***equilibrium*** mole amounts implies the same in the ***initial*** mole amounts.

In other acid-base problems this may be avoided by including an additional mass balance, charge balance, and auto-ionization of water.  Here it appears to be insufficient.  I am wondering if this is because of missing data (e.g., volume) or is there something more profound going on?

Comment: I don't see why it is necessary to do those extra calculations. Notice eq. 3 is actually henderson hasselbalch equation when you take -log of both sides. However, in this case, simply Ka = [H+] so [A-] = [HA] at equilibrium. By adding the exact same moles of NaA, it would not shift the equilibrium at all.

Comment: Yes, I know HH is just the log of eqn 3.  I am trying not to then assume that the final equilibrium concentrations may be replaced by the initial concentrations.

Comment: I think that is always the case because if you add equimolar amounts of NaA and HA initially, the equilibrium would not change and initial concentrations should equal equilibrium concentrations. Just make an ICE table and you will find that x has to equal 0. It could just be me misunderstanding the question and if that is the case, sorry.

Comment: The equilibrium ratio always somewhat shifts wrt initial ratio, because H+ ions are made from HA. But as the task is set, it is assumed negligible, with assumption [HA]>>[H+]. Otherwise, more input data would be needed, like volume or concentration.

Comment: @Poutnik  Thanks for the confirmation.  That is exactly what I was wondering.  I know it shifts and granted usually (as here) [HA]>>[H+].  It is really obvious that volume (or concentration) is needed?  That is, I am wondering is there no exact way in which to get the answer?

Comment: @ML I think you are misunderstanding and it is surely my fault.  There is a shift in the molar amounts of both HA and A- due to the production of H+.  While typically small, this will make the final equilibrium values appearing in both HH and my Eqn 3 no longer quite equal to the initial values.  An ICE table is in effect what my Eqn 1 and Eqn 3 are.  That is, I do not think x is zero.

Comment: The degree of ionization is concentration dependent. To keep the same pH at 10 times higher dilution, 10 times more of acid has to be ionized. so you need higher initial HA/A ratio for more diluted solutions. Or, the other way, the same initial ratio would lead to high pH for more diluted solutions.

Comment: @Poutnik  I agree.  So I think your conclusion is mine: that there is no way to rigorously get an answer with the data given?

Comment: Without assumptions, no, there is no rigorous way. But I think you overcomplicate it, I would take the assumption and was done with it.

Comment: Well I am not trying to solve this problem.  I am more interested in this class of problem.  I am curious when these assumptions fall apart.  Thanks for the help.